# what is the meaning of these sentences? "You know where the drop is going down."

Tags: sentence-starts

A police man said this to a man, and I don't understand the bold part.

> I know Caruso is a rat and I'm gonna clean up this sewer. **You know where the drop is going down**. Now give it up. Hey, I'll smack it outta ya.

Comment: This is pseudo-lowlife/criminal patois. The "drop" is the exchange, possible the sale of drugs or weapons (or the clandestine storage of illicit goods, for later retrieval by a different party). Where it is "going down" is where it is occurring. Hence the sentence means "You know where the exchange is taking place. Tell me, or I'll beat you up".

Answer (score 3):

By **You know where the drop is going down.** the speaker is referring to the location of where the exchange of an *item / package* is going to happen. Either that or he/she is referring to the location where some *person / item / package* is actually going to be dropped from the air via helicopter / airplane of sorts. Although I suspect it to be the former.

This language is commonly found in the dialect of thiefs, drug dealers and such people or even sometimes police.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [drop](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drop)

It means a predetermined location for the deposit and subsequent removal of secret communications or illicit goods, such as drugs or the act of depositing such communications or materials. The police officer is interested in knowing the location of such a transaction.