# Is there a Latinate, plural noun for "illicit possessions"?

Tags: single-word-requests

While composing this [comment on an earlier question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323026/what-is-the-meaning-of-these-sentences-you-know-where-the-drop-is-going-down#comment734945_323026), I got hung up after "clandestine storage".

I felt myself grasping for a single word, styled after *errata*, *desiderata*, *stigmata*, etc, which means "illicit or illegal goods or possessions".

This is a strict [single-word-request](/questions/tagged/single-word-request): does there exist a single, plural, Latinate (meaning ending in *-ata* or otherwise sounding official or bureaucratic) which means "stuff you shouldn't have"?

Something that would fit into this blank:

> In the wake of the bust, the police confiscated the rival gangs' ***________***, including three kilograms of cocaine,  a trunk full of marijuana, six fully automatic assault rifles, a bandolier of grenades, ten assorted illegal stiletto knives, and [several lewd pictures of kittens](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArsonMurderAndJaywalking).

Comment: "purloined goods" but that's two words, hence a comment not an answer. .

Comment: @P.Obertelli They don't have to be purloined. They can be legitimately purchased, but still verboten (like buying pot from a drug dealer: prohibited, but not purloined).

Comment: Maybe just contraband?

Comment: @Nick Oh, contraband is good. I'll upvote you if you post that as an answer (with a dictionary definition etc). Lemme check the thesaurus for synonyms (I'm looking for something that "sounds plural"). Thanks dude.

Comment: Lol, or you could also just make up a word by taking one of the latin words meaning "to steal" and taking its 4th principle part in the neuter plural perfect passive participle form. After all, that's how you get things like *errata*.

Comment: I'll put up contraband in an hour or two though.

Comment: @Nick I can barely conjugate in English. That said, the root wouldn't be to *steal* (see my earlier comment directed at P. Obertelli), it would have to cover things like mom finding old girly mags in her son's mattress (which he bought with good money).

Comment: @dan bron If you want to be very technical,  an illegal good can not be  "legitimately purchased" by law. You could not go to court because your pot dealer did not deliver the goods paid for, for example. As far as I know, in most country, a contract on an illegal good is null, therefore you can never legitimately be the owner of such good. But I agree, they might not be stolen event though they cannot be legally owned.

Comment: @ dan bron still not one word, but the most "latinate" I could find: "Illicit goods" . That encompass anything which cannot be sold legitimately, whatever the reason, contraband is specific to import/export. See for example http://www.interpol.int/Crime-areas/Trafficking-in-illicit-goods-and-counterfeiting/Trafficking-in-illicit-goods-and-counterfeiting

Comment: @P.Obertelli Yes, thank you, I used "illicit goods" in the original comment, and this question was motivated by a desire for a single-word substitute (mostly because my brain is *insisting* one exists, of the *-ata* variety, and that I've used it before; most likely though I am misremembering). I don't think *contraband* is restricted to import/export, though of course that's one context (of many) where the word is employed.

Comment: Booty? Ill-gotten gains? (Both anglosaxon)

Comment: @Mitch You can't really call a concealed (and illegal) weapon *booty*, right? And while the mags in Jr's mattress may indeed be entitled *Booty!*, I don't imagine they qualify as *booty*? Try not to get hung up on only the category of contraband which is stolen.

Comment: ??? Most of the items mentioned are not illegal weapons (which, yes, guns are not usually thought of as booty)

Comment: @Mitch It depends on the jurisdiction, I imagine. Both fully automatic rifles and grenades are illegal to own without a special license (rarely and begrudgingly given) from the police (not he state) here in NYC. Also certain kinds of non-ballistic / explosive weapons like stilettos and nunchucks. But anyway, something doesn't have to be *illegal* to be *illicit*; I got in trouble once in Morocco because I didn't know you were supposed to take your shoes off before entering a mosque (also you have to be Muslim). And I'm sure candy bars are contraband in fat camps, but not illegal, obviously.

Comment: Notwithstanding the above discussion of the relevancy or not of "Illegal" to your question, since we’ve unfortunately succeeded in turning “illegal” into an overly specific (and, imo, offensive) noun in English, maybe it’s not too late to convince the Latin-speaking world to do the same with their “inlegalis” with the hope that they expand it to mean anything that’s “illegal,” depending on the context!

Comment: @PapaPoule I think instead of convincing the Latin world to term unregistered migrants "inlegalisii", we should get them to call them *Goths*!

Comment: Don't confuse the endings of Latin *desiderata* and Greek *stigmata*. Those aren't related.

Comment: @tchrist I had actually wondered about that, but was too lazy to check. Is one hole in one hand still a "stigmata"?

Answer (score 5):

As user [@Nick](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/126955/nick) offered in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323051/is-there-a-latinate-plural-noun-for-illicit-possessions#comment735037_323051):

> The word [**contraband**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraband), reported in English since 1529, from Medieval French contrebande "a smuggling," denotes any item which, relating to its nature, **is illegal to be possessed or sold**. –Wiki

Comment: "(usually uncountable, plural contrabands)" –[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contraband)

Answer (score 2):

Lots of comments but no answers, so I'll take a shot.

[illicita](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/illicitus#Latin)

> Plural neuter accusative of *illicitus*: 
>   forbidden, unlawful, illegal, illicit

or

[praeda](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praeda)

> 1. plunder, spoils of war, booty
> 2. prey, game taken in the hunt
> 3. gain, profit

Comment: Nice. If you can dig up any evidence of *illicita* being un-self-consciously used in an English text, or listed in a (professional) dictionary, I'll accept this answer.